Is is possible to have multiple lines in a switch statement of C# 8?
In C# 8 we have the return switch statement, which looks like this:
return a switch
{
    1 => "op1",
    2 => "op2",
    3 => "op3",
    _ => "default"
};

Is it possible to log something before returning? For example:
return a switch
{
    1 => { Console.WriteLine("op1"); return "op1"; },
    2 => "op2",
    3 => "op3",
    _ => "default"
};


C# switch expression aims to return value by pattern match. For your scenario, you should use the traditional switch statement.

And I don't see any reason to log the same value as the return value (expression). You can just log it after the (value) assignment of the switch expression.

As @YongShun already indicated, there is nothing like a "return switch statement". What you have here is a "return statement" with a "swicth expression".

You can customize a "LogAndReturn" function.

A method call is an expression but can contain a block statement.

Good point @shingo. I asked this for debugging purposes only, sometimes I want to print something in a switch real quick, so writing a function wasn't what I was looking for, but having a generic LogAndReturn<T>(string msg, T value) function that can be used everywhere could be handy.

See Proposal: Block-bodied switch expression arms #3037.

Taking a page from javascript:
return a switch
{
    1 => ((Func<string>) (() => { Console.WriteLine("op1"); return "op1";}))(),
    2 => "op2",
    3 => "op3",
    _ => "default"
};

If I have to review this I want to see a really good reason why this is isn't a switch statement though.
I've had to do something like this in an exception filter a few times, where you can't put a statement. It's the kind of thing nobody likes but every once in awhile has to be done.

interesting. never thought about it. I assume the function can be extracted into a variable and then called switchfunc()

I would never use such monster in the final version of my code, I asked for debugging purposes only. Looks like I won't use this for debugging either, it's too cumbersome to write.

Dare say if it's something required often for debugging a small generic method like static T DebugPrintAndReturn<T>(T arg) { Console.Write(arg); return arg; } would mean you could 1=>DebugPrintAndReturn("opt1")

This looks like it is going to have a lot of unnecessary overhead; I'd strongly recommend simply using an old-style switch statement instead of a switch expression here.

I don't get why logging after the assignment isn't a thing. Maybe the example is under complex but to me, there is no benefit of doing it in the switch.

@Fildor sometimes one is writing a function which the only thing it does is returning a switch, so the function would have no body. In this case, it would be necessary to create a body for the function to print. It might not be a compelling reason but it exists.
